# Adding events to a calendar in android

Tags: android

I want to add events ,ie add remainders to the calendar in android.

Is that possible?

Comment: not related to programming; the question is better asked on android.stackexchange.com, and you need to be more precise when writing question, as is, I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar API in android is not a documented API.  Google discourages the use of undocumented APIs.  This article, though, will get you started.

http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm